# How to get the rate of the regerssion?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I start to learn the machine learning shorly. I meet a problem when I read the book of PRML. It talk about the LMS algorithm and use it to solve the problem of the regression. 
   **wi+1 = wi + alpha*gradient**
   I don't know how to determine the 'alpha'.
   So, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

`alpha` is the learning_rate or step size (of gradient descent). It is a critical parameter we want to tune, so you could start with a list of options, like:

```
0.1, 0.01, 0.001, ...
```

and see which one works better with respect to training time and prediction accuracy. If the learning_rate is too high, you might see the cost is not decreasing (or even increasing). On the other hand, if it is too low, you might notice the learning is taking too long to converge to a good state.

If you use tensorflow (or other library/tools), to implement the algorithm you would need to choose an optimizer, for example, a [GradientDescentOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#GradientDescentOptimizer). You will notice the first argument is a `learning_rate`.

```
learning_rate: A Tensor or a floating point value. The learning rate to use.
```